# I want to click buttons one by one and add delay. how to add delay

Tags: javascript

this is my code:

```
let asd = document.querySelectorAll('#ID');
asd.forEach(btn => btn.click());
```

I want to click one by one how to add delay in java sript

Comment: FYI It's best to keep id unique. Did you mean a css class instead?

Answer (score 0):

use The **setTimeout()** method that calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.
Note: 1000 ms = 1 second.

```
   let asd = document.querySelectorAll('#ID');
    asd.forEach(btn =>{ 
    setTimeout(function(){
    btn.click() 
     }, 3000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function to iterate over the elements with the delay. Also, you need to use a common `class` instead of `id` since you have several elements. Here is a complete example:

```js
let asd = document.querySelectorAll('.ID');

let i = 0;
const interval = setInterval(function() {
     if(i == asd.length)
          clearInterval(interval);
     if(asd[i])
          asd[i].click();
     i++;
}, 2000);

//add listeners
let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('ID');
for(let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
     btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
           console.log("click "+(i+1));
     })
}
```

```html
<button class="ID">Click 1</button>
<button class="ID">Click 2</button>
<button class="ID">Click 3</button>
```